# KHAF runway 30 ODP in the works, appears to be missing a segment

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures, ifr-navigation

*Asked the FAA about this & they replied that the procedure has been redesigned since the one at the link was posted, that the old charts will be removed from the website, and that the newly designed procedure is currently in QC.*

A long delayed ODP for runway 30 at KHAF can be found on the FAA website at [this link](https://www.faa.gov/aero_docs/acifp/2017071023410701005-HAF/CA_KHAF_ODP_HALF%20MOON%20BAY_ONE_S.pdf). (Was supposed to be published in 2020, now scheduled for 2023.) The graphical portion is below. The text reads

> TAKEOFF RWY 30: Climb to 1100, then climbing left turn on heading 150° and on PYE R-144 to HADLY, then on OSI R-255 to OSI VOR/DME. Cross OSI VOR/DME at or above 3500 before proceeding on course.

My questions are twofold. One is that the drawing indicates intercepting PYE R-144 from the left. This would be a hugely wide turn from 1100' off R30 at HAF. But even leaving that aside, and assuming they just drew it this way to reduce clutter, is it normal to not indicate on an ODP *how* you are supposed to intercept a radial? If you do a standard rate turn to 150 after climbing to 1100' you will end up well to the east of PYE R-144 on a parallel track (according to my sketch in Foreflight, which shows PYE R-144 having a bearing of 149 there) and never end up at HADLY. Of course this depends on the speed of the plane. But even at 200 knots (below the B shelf here) I estimate a 150 degree standard rate turn (from 300 left to 150) takes ~2 nm of linear distance, far less than the 5 nm or so between KHAF and PYE R-144. To make this work you really need to do something like "climbing left turn heading 190 to intercept PYE R-144". But you can't really tell that from the (misleading) diagram or the text.

ODPs weren't a big part of my IR training, so I'm wondering if this is common and you're just supposed to join the radial however you want to make the procedure work (*i.e.,* using a steep enough intercept so that you join before HADLY).

[image: Half Moon Bay One departure]

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it would be better suited as an answer so everyone can see that this has, in fact been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Asked the FAA about this & they replied that the procedure has been redesigned since the one at the link was posted, that the old charts will be removed from the website, and that the newly designed procedure is currently in QC.

Comment: In case anyone still cares, the SEEMS departure now exists and for piston singles it stinks. Takes you 6 miles offshore. I got assigned it the other day when I said I was departing 30. In the future I'll stick to departing off 12 when I need IFR to get out.